# How can I use Page Builder only on some WYSIWYG UI components in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I have Page Builder enabled in the configuration settings, but on some WYSIWYG UI components I would like to use the regular TinyMCE editor. Is this possible at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
```

Add the above snippet to the ui_componenet configuration.